# About to make google search console for my food blogger

Tags: discussion

I have a food blogger, I would like to make a google search console but I really can not do it right. Can I ask you for help?

Comment: Creating a custom search for a blog is probably more suited to the main StackOverflow.com since it's more closely about web development than recipes or cooking.

Comment: Axil rose, welcome! I’m afraid that this has nothing to do with cooking per se - so it’s [not within our scope](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The [tour] and [help] will explain the details of how the site works. Questions about a site per se belong on the corresponding [meta] page.

Comment: Even on main stackoverflow, you should describe what you did to achieve your target and how is that not working, to get better responses. There is an entire tag for [google search console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) there.

Answer (score 6):

This site is clearly geared towards *cooking*, so I’m afraid that your question is outside of our scope.

A good rule of thumb is to substitute “cooking” with something else. If the core question would remain the same, it’s not about cooking as defined in our [help].

You don’t need cooking expertise (which we could supply), you need help with a data processing topic (which we can’t help you with).

A general hint:
All SE sites have a set of help pages that explain what is on topic for that specific site. It’s highly recommended to browse through them before posting, this should help you to find the right place and give valuable hints about what  a good question should contain - which in turn will mean answers that are helpful for you.